# emails not deliver to hotmail account Using yii2 swiftmailer

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

While sending email from my website emails delivered to gmail accounts but Emails not deliver to Hotmail account, i am using yii2 swift mailer configuration in yii2 config file

```
`mailer' => [
      'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
      'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
      'useFileTransport' => false,
      'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'mail.sample.in',
            'username' => 'develop@sample.in',
            'password' => 'dev98761XXX',
            'port' => '25',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
      ],
],
```

Comment: please give configure code.

Comment: This is the code give in common/config/main-local.php

Comment: Most likely not your code, rather some filtering on the receiving mail server. Sending emails is somewhat tricky as it involves the reputation of the sending mail server.

Comment: please help me i am stucked